# How do game server route client with the same room code?

Tags: sockets, game-development

I understand that alot of games uses socket to establish room in a server where each client within a game room talk a one particular server, but in multi server environment the loadbalancer is not necessary going to route the client to a particular server initially, so what is the mechanism that makes all the client establish a socket connection to the same server given same room code?

Comment: Do you have a particular load balancer in mind? The simplest solution would be: the client connects to that server and a load balancer is not used.

Comment: but in a multi server environment, there needs a mechanism to determine which server is used right?

Comment: so the client can ask any server which server is the right one - or it can ask a different server whose only job is to tell clients which servers are the right ones - up to you